# Does using Spark of light affect the story?

Tags: destiny

I am new to Destiny and I got a Spark of Light.

Will using it affect the story or will I be able to play through it, but at a higher level?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not affect the story, it merely sets your level to 25. It does unlock  [The Taken King Story Missions](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Story_Missions) and [and equips the character with level appropriate gear](http://www.destinygamewiki.com/wiki/Spark_of_Light). Since the level requirement for the other missions seems to be below level 25, all those missions will unlock as well.

**Note**: [You do NOT gain 25 levels of experience](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3ho6my/spark_of_light/). You will be a "fresh" level 25 player, meaning you cannot allocate points into skills or anything.

Comment: It should unlock all missions up to taken king as well.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The way they list the quests accompanied by their level requirement: Yes, it should unlock all missions up to taken king. I have added it to my answer for clarification, thanks.

Comment: It unlocks the mission, but it does not mark it as complete. You will still need to follow the story sequencially to actually complete it.