# How does experience work, how does it relate to levels

Tags: destiny

I just started playing the destiny demo a few days ago and decided to buy it, after that I got a spark of light.

I decided not to use it on my first character and save it for another one if I make one. While investigating the consequences of using the spark of light I learned that the spark of light does not award experience but instead awards levels, what could this mean?

[from reddit:](https://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/3ho6my/spark_of_light/cvbf6zb)

> You simply level to 25 with no additional experience in your subclass trees. So essentially, you're a fresh level 25 character with no abilities unlocked in your subclass tree of choice. You're a level 25 character with the same amount of experience as a level 1.

[Does using Spark of light affect the story?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247798/does-using-spark-of-light-affect-the-story)

> Note: You do NOT gain 25 levels of experience. You will be a "fresh" level 25 player, meaning you cannot allocate points into skills or anything.

Does this mean that there is a disadvantage to using the spark of light? Is it better to level up to 25, by better I mean will you have a more powerfull character that leveled to 25 than if you used the spark of light?

Answer (score 4):

Just about everything in Destiny has an experience level - your character, your subclasses, and your gear.  What Spark of Light does is increase your character level to 25, with 0 experience toward level 26, and without any subclass levels.  So, in effect you are at a disadvantage compared to people who are level 25 from getting experience, since they'll have some gear and more importantly probably at least one subclass completely leveled and one partway there.  That said, you aren't going to be at any huge disadvantage, the subclasses level fairly quickly and once you have their basic abilities the other abilities you get are icing on the cake for questing.  Probably the biggest issue would be if you want to enter the Crucible (PvP), since you will be at a significant disadvantage there.  That said, as a level 25 character playing against level 40s, you are already at a huge disadvantage, since even though damage is all normalized they have better effects on their weapons and armor.

As an aside, I think you made the right decision playing through the first 25 levels for your first character, I'm actually kind of surprised they allow you to use a spark of light on your first character.  That way you get to do all the vanilla quests once while it's all still new to you.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a Spark of Light, your character becomes level 25 and gets gear appropriate for that level.

What does not happen is that none of your subclasses level up along with you. If you were to get your character to level 25 naturally, and focused on one subclass for that entire time, it would either be maxed out or close to it. After using a Spark of Light, you will still have a long way to go towards maxing out a subclass.

I would agree with your choice - don't use a Spark of Light on your first character, but use it on an alt to make the leveling process a bit easier.

Comment: At level 40, I was just over half way to maxxing one subclass. I only used the one subclass, so that is with all the xp from levelling. Being a higher level, it is much easier to earn xp, so maxxing all classes from there was much easier.